# Js function to check if method throws

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Imagine I have class `Foo` and method `bar`.

```
class Foo {
    bar() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need universal function `isThrows` to check if method `bar` throws or not. Is it possible?

Comment: this question makes no sense? Do you mean `try{} catch{}`?

Comment: No. I need function which will be accept method as param and check if method throws in its body. With try{} catch{}.

Comment: why? this is very bizare?

Comment: I need a lot of such checks in my tests. I don't want to write try{} catch{} again and again.

Comment: @melihovv Why aren't you using your test framework's method for asserting an error is thrown?

Comment: @melihovv: I don't think that you can do this. you should every time write try{} catch{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write such function.

```
function isThrows(obj, method, ...args) {
    var result = false;
    try {
        method.apply(obj, args);
    } catch (e) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Use

```
const foo = new Foo();
const result = isThrows(foo, foo.bar/*, additional params if needed */);
```